# Is there a reason a function is made public and then called internally in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, design-patterns

I have come across a popular smart contract in the OpenZeppelin library that manages access control of a contract.
This is the library:
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol

Looking at the last two functions, `transferOwnership` is marked `public` and `virtual`  and calls `_transferOwnership` to perform its functionality basically, which is marked as `internal` and `virtual`. What does this pattern achieve? Or why isn't simply like this:

```
 function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public virtual onlyOwner {
        require(newOwner != address(0), "Ownable: new owner is the zero address");
        address oldOwner = _owner;
        _owner = newOwner;
        emit OwnershipTransferred(oldOwner, newOwner);
    }
```

Is is because `transferOwnership` has a modifier which restricts access, so it won't make sense to make it internal?

Does it have to do something with security or reusability or the virtual modifier?

Answer (score 0):

When a chunk of code is used by more than one Function, the best practice is not to repeat writing the same chunk of code in each Function and instead transfer that chunk of code to a separate function and call it wherever needed.
You will notice `_transferOwnership` is required by `constructor` , `renounceOwnership` and `transferOwnership` 
`_transferOwnership` itself is marked internal because it should be available for internal calls.